# Weibull MLE in R

Tags: r, mle, weibull

The loglikelihood function [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHjvQ.jpg). I wrote to this a function in R, this return of negative one times the loglikelihood. I generated a vector with rWeibull with parameters shape=1.5, scale=0.5. But when i call the nlm function with my loglikelihood function, the estimated values for the parameters are: 2.124180 and 4.003675. What wrong with my R code?
The code:

```
vec<-rWeibull(n=1000, params=list(shape=1.5, scale=0.5))
weibull_loglik<-function(parm){
n<-length(vec)
gamma<-parm[1]
lambda<-parm[2]
loglik<-n*log(gamma/lambda)+(gamma-1)*sum(vec-log((lambda^(gamma-1))))-sum((vec/lambda)^gamma)
return(-loglik)}
weibull<-nlm(weibull_loglik,parm<-c(1,1), hessian=TRUE)
weibull$estimate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log-likelihood is not correct. I get correct estimates when I use `dweibull(..., log=TRUE)`:

```
vec <- rweibull(n=1000, shape=1.5, scale=0.5)
weibull_loglik <- function(parm){
  n <- length(vec)
  gamma <- parm[1]
  lambda <- parm[2]
  loglik <- sum(dweibull(vec, shape=gamma, scale=lambda, log=TRUE))
  return(-loglik)
}
weibull <- nlm(weibull_loglik, p = c(1,1), hessian=TRUE)

> weibull$estimate
[1] 1.5547181 0.5116119
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
loglik<-n*log(gamma/lambda)+(gamma-1)*sum(vec)-log((lambda^(gamma-1)))-
sum((vec/lambda)^gamma)
```

As you do not sum over the third part of the LogLik-function.